# Javascript - convert a text with accents, spaces and capitals to one without accents with hyphens and lowercase

Tags: javascript, string, cross-browser, normalization, backwards-compatibility

I want convert to text with accents, spaces and capitals to one without accents with hyphens and lowercase.

my solution is:

```js
var text = 'Canción del Amor';
const nt = text.replace(/\s+/g, '-').normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '').toLowerCase();

console.log(nt);
```

please can you help me with a better solution. Since I want it to be compatible with all browsers.

Comment: your "solution" doesn't work at all because `texto` and `text` are not the same variable

Comment: @JaromandaX I think it's fair to assume that was a typo.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - yes, assuming that, and now the code works, I can't see a reason this question is on topic

Comment: @JaromandaX [`normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) is an ES6 method. The question specifically asks for an alternative approach that has better browser compatibility.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - as far as I can see only Internet Exploder isn't supported - isn't it time we just said to people who still use Internet Explorer ***I'm sorry, you're using a browser that is extremely insecure so you're too stupid to browse the internet, please don't visit this site again***

Comment: @JaromandaX depends on your target audience. If you're selling a large business application, you'll need to cater support to legacy networks still running on Windows XP, which only has Internet Explorer 8. Sometimes it's so expensive to upgrade company infrastructure that it makes more financial sense to continue supporting it than to start the long process of overhaul. You don't always have the luxury of dropping support for whoever you want.

Comment: True. But highly doubt thats relevant to the op

Comment: @JaromandaX  - I try to find a better solution for browser compatibility.

Comment: Another solution that seemed good to me was this: 

var nt = "Canción de Amor";

function cleanUpSpecialChars(str)
{
    return str
        .replace(/[á]/g,"a")
        .replace(/['é']/g,"e")
        .replace(/['í']/g,"i")
        .replace(/['ó']/g,"o")
        .replace(/['ú']/g,"u")
        .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
}
console.log(cleanUpSpecialChars(nt).toLowerCase());

Comment: re IE support (which is the ONLY browser this would need a hack for) - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Windows-IT-Pro-Blog/The-perils-of-using-Internet-Explorer-as-your-default-browser/ba-p/331732 ... even MicroSoft wants you to stop using it

Answer (score 0):

You can continue to use this solution, granted you use a polyfill like [unorm](https://github.com/walling/unorm). Placing a

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/unorm@1.4.1/lib/unorm.js"></script>
```

above any usage of [`String.prototype.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) should allow the function to work in older browsers that only support ECMAScript 5.

I do not suggest reinventing the wheel for the `normalize()` method; unicode normalization requires some fairly complex string manipulation and you're much better off using a solution that already works.